# Trouble using new NSNumbeFormatter

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I have an app which read an import in a TextField then process it using

```
let number = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(numberString)
if let number = number {
    let floatValue = Float(number)
}
```

While I'm working with regional formats which use comma as decimal separator (like Italy or Germany) everything works (I can write 17,80 or 17.80 and they work both). When I work with regional formats which use dot as decimal separator (like USA), when I use dot as decimal separator (17.80) OK but if I use comma (17,80) app crash!

How can I solve it?

Comment: Collin is right, my question is to understand the reason of this problem, I haven't asked how to convert a string with comma to a string with decimal!

Answer (score 0):

Would looking at the string and changing it to whichever format you know (e.g. making it always use a decimal separator) won't cause problems be a viable fix here?

Comment: Best thing would be to understand why with some regional formats comma works and with other crash. Otherwise a solution could be check if TextField.text contains a comma and replace it with a dot.

Comment: I agree -- the best thing would definitely be to understand the underlying reason and fix it that way. Hence why I said replacing the characters would be a "fix" and not a "solution".